# How can I get rid of choppy videos in the Focal Fossa 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, kubuntu, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

My Kubuntu 20.04 faces choppy videos in browsers (firefox, chromium) as well as in VLC. The video freezes very frequently (once in every 5/6 seconds). But I do not have any problem with the audio of that same video file. I've added graphics driver from `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`, but with no luck. Below is computer configuration:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64 
Host: HP Spectre Pro x360 G1 
Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 2560x1440 
DE: Plasma 
WM: KWin 
WM Theme: Layan 
Theme: ChromeOSDark [Plasma], Mojave-dark-alt [GTK2/3] 
Icons: McMuse-dark [Plasma], McMuse-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 11 
CPU: Intel i5-5200U (4) @ 2.700GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5500 
Memory: 3112MiB / 7869MiB
```

Also following is the `vainfo` of my computer:

```
vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 20.1.1 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
```

**Additional info.**

Output of `lspci -v | less` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 5500
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
        Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Output of `lshw -numeric -C display` :

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:b1000000-b1ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Output of `glxinfo -B | less` :

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) (0x1616)
    Version: 20.2.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.2.0-devel (git-8b8ffb1 2020-07-02 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.2.0-devel (git-8b8ffb1 2020-07-02 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.2.0-devel (git-8b8ffb1 2020-07-02 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Answer (score 1):

The Intel HD Graphics 5500 is a mid-range graphics chip from 2015. Most graphics issues are driver-related, however, issues from 2015 were likely resolved long ago.

- Your resolution is quite high, so try a lower resolution, 1920*1080 for example.
  Check also that you have all the latest OS updates.
  You may also want to check if there are any alternative drivers available, even if proprietary.
- Search for 'Additional drivers' in your applications, and see if the system offers different drivers. Try the latest 'tested' one.
- Check your CPU usage with `top` when playing a problematic video. You may find that although you have plenty of RAM, etc, you may be CPU bound.